# Search dropdown suggestions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

Is there a better way to build an input box with a dropdown list for suggestion other than the following?

```
<div id="dropdown-group" class="input-group dropdown">
    <input id="keyword" type="search" class="form-control">

    <ul id="suggestion-list" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="link">
                <img class="img-sm" src="img_path">
                <span>name</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

`input-group`, `dropdown`, `form-control` and `dropdown-menu` are all *bootstrap* classes.
I use `vuejs` and `ajax` to fill the unordered list (`#suggestion-list`) as the user types in the search input field (`#keyword`).
I also listen to the input lost and get focus, where I add and remove the *bootstrap* class `open` to open and close the dropdown list. I deliberately skipped that `javascript` code to focus on html and css.

What is missing is when the functionality to hit the arrow-down key to browse the suggestion list.

Is there a better way to design such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [this](https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-typeahead). See it in action [here](http://pespantelis.github.io/vue-typeahead/). It doesn't matter what you want to do, there's always someone smarter and faster who's done it already.

Comment: true. Thanks a lot :D